# Filter a list based on the most found keywords

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out how to filter the list by keywords, but filter where it has most of the keywords but does not require them all.

Keywords:

```
{"test", "find", "me","where","am","i"}
```

List would be:

```
{ "find me", "test where am i", "find me where am i"}
```

The output I would like is:

```
"find me where am i"
```

Comment: do you mean you need output from the list where any one of the keyword is missing ?

Comment: @Amit Verma , I think he need the string which has most number of keywords in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
var keywords = new List<string> { "test", "find", "me", "where", "am", "i" };
var list = new List<string> { "find me", "test where am i", "find me where am i" };

var filtered = 
    list.Select(li => (item: li, count: keywords.Count(k => li.Contains(k))))
        .GroupBy(x => x.count)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
        .First()
        .Select(x => x.item)
        .ToList();
```

This basically checks each item in the list against the keywords, groups by the number of found keywords, and then selects the one(s) with the most found keywords.

**Note:**

Using `.Contains()` will accept keywords even when they're part of another words. If the found keywords must be whole words <sup>(which is probably true)</sup>, you can adjust the logic to use [Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) as follows:

```
list.Select(li => (item: li, count: keywords.Count(k => Regex.IsMatch(li, $@"\b{k}\b"))))
```

Comment: `keywords` should be a `HashSet<String>` (maybe with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`) otherwise you'll have horrid runtime complexity.

Comment: @Dai isn't HashSet slower than linear lookups up to a point? I would probably stick to list of keywords up to 50 items or so.

Comment: @Dai clearly this is just demonstration of a concept. It is obvious that actual code should use HashSet (instead of list) and MaxBy (instead of OrderByDescending)... but we should not offend OP of the question by suggesting they may not understand that.

Comment: @Dai Using a HashSet is a good idea because the keywords shouldn't contain duplicates, yes. But I fail to see how it could improve performance _in this particular case_. We're not trying to find elements in `kewords`, but rather in `list`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Are you talking about MoreLinq's MaxBy or was it add it to a newer version of .NET?

Comment: @41686d6564 I don't think there is is one in any version of .Net :(  - either [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) or one should be able to write one themselves in couple minutes... Anything that is O(n) compared to sorting with O(n log n) ... Indeed it is easier to show an example with OrderBy as it is part of framework... like everyone does for shuffling list too.

Comment: @41686d6564 for `HashSet` - correct check is to tokenize incoming string and than check if each token is in the HashSet. Otherwise something like "tester somewhere amending finder" would be top hit by comparison shown in the answer... again the code just to show idea.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov _"tester somewhere amending finder"_ That's exactly why there's a Regex solution at the end of the answer :) That said, the code can be improved, of course. As you said, it's just to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: @41686d6564 agree that proper regex is likely faster than first option - you get the count in a single pass and compiled regexes are quite optimized. Maybe I'll try to compare and see if my guess is right.